# Reduce emissions of Flux based on value?

Tags: kotlin, project-reactor

I'm having following flux:

```
val myFlux = Flux.fromIterable(listOf("A", "A", "B", "C", "C"))
```

Elements inside this flux are sorted and flux itself is huge (we can assume that it's infinite)

I would like to map it into `Flux<String>` where each `String` would contain `AA` `B` `CC` respectively.

It can be also `Flux<SomeDomainObject>` where each `SomeDomainObject` would contain same keys (eg. `AA`)

I cannot use `groupBy` since number of keys would be huge.

Desired Flux behavior:
[image: desired flux behavior]

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit on the use case? Are "A"s always sequential, or you could have another "A" at the end and still need to group it? Could you describe the general rule here?

Comment: Ok, updated the question - "A"'s are sequential and whole `Flux` can be assumed to be infinite

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the `bufferUntil`-Function: https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#bufferUntil-java.util.function.Predicate-boolean-

```
fun<T> newItem(): Predicate<T> {
    var lastItem: T? = null

    return Predicate<T> { newItem ->
        when {
            lastItem == null -> {
                lastItem = newItem
                false
            }
            lastItem != newItem -> {
                lastItem = newItem
                true
            }
            else -> false
        }
    }
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val flux = Flux.just("A", "A", "B", "C", "C")
    val buffered = flux.bufferUntil(newItem(), true).map { it.joinToString("") }

    buffered.subscribe {
        println(it)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this code snippet:

```
Flux<String> letters = Flux.just("A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "C", "C");
Flux<String> sequence = letters.bufferUntil(new Predicate<String>() {

        private AtomicReference<String> currentLetter = new AtomicReference<>("");

        @Override
        public boolean test(String letter) {
            String current = currentLetter.getAndSet(letter);
            return current.equals(letter);
        }
    }).map(list -> String.join("", list));
```

Comment: `bufferWhile` will skip the element, that triggers the new buffer. See documentation: https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#bufferWhile-java.util.function.Predicate-

Comment: Ah, yet, right. The marbles diagram is wrong there.

Comment: `bufferUntil` should return `true` to open a new buffer. Your solution returns `false`. And you need to use the variant with the parameter `cutBefore=true`. Otherwise each buffer will include one wrong element.